# Need help to combine two rules in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a problem, I need to redirect the user to the https when it comes from the http, but also need a second rule to feed the url to the MVC. Both rules work but not when combined. Why?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pamisla\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://pamisla.com

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?s).*)$ index.php?_url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: How are you trying to combine them?

Comment: In a way that if someone goes to http:// example.com/cart.php, that converts into https:// exmaple.com/index.php?_url=cart.php

Comment: You said "both work but not when combined" so how did you combine them that didn't work?

Comment: when I test each one separated they work, when put together in the same file, they dont

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Thank you miken32.

```
# force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L] 

# rewrite the url for the MVC   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?s).*)$ index.php?_url=$1 [QSA,L]
```